# How to convert names created with Excel's Name Box from workbook-scoped to worksheet-scoped?

Tags: microsoft-excel, cells, named-ranges

I created A LOT of names of cells in an Excel worksheet using the Name Box (to the left of the Formula Bar). Then, I decided to make a different version of the worksheet in the same workbook. And then another version and so on.

When I check the Name Manager window, I see a mix of workbook- and worksheet-scoped name.

Just in case, I would like to convert workbook-scoped to worksheet-scoped names. Is there an easy way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just make a copy of the sheet containing book-scoped names in the same book and then delete the original sheet containing book-scoped names. The names of any pasted sheet are sheet-scoped.

To identify the sheet with book-scoped names, look for the sheet whose name does not appear in the Names Manager window, which you can access selecting the ribbon's tab named Formulas.

To make a copy of a sheet, right-click its tab. Choose "Move or Copy". Click Create a Copy. You can select the copied sheet to insert the new sheet before it.

To delete the original sheet, right-click its tab. Click Delete.

Excel names the new sheet with the name of the copied one plus a number in parenthesis to prevent the existence of two sheets with the same name. You may want to rename the new sheet to delete the added characters.